# Is it true that for any integer a and prime number p, there are infinitely many intergers n that satisfy p|a^n+n?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it true that for any integer $a$ and prime number $p$, there exist infinitely many integers $n$ that satisfy $p|a^n+n$?

Well,I found it correct as when $n=(kp+1)(p-1)$, $a^n+n\equiv1+kp^2+p-kp-1\equiv0 \mod p$

But I want to know if it's possible when  $n\equiv1(\text{mod}\ p-1)$.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Where is this problem from?

Comment: *integer* has one *r*

Comment: ... and there are no "infinite integers".

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Mod $p,$ the value of $a^n$ depends only on $n$ modulo $p-1.$

Answer (score 0):

Well if $p|a$ then for any $n$ be any multiple of $p$ it is true.

If $p\not\mid a$ then let $n=k(p-1)+r$.  Then $a^n\equiv a^r\pmod p$ (F.L.T) and $a^n + n \equiv a^r -k + r\pmod p$.

So for any $r$ we like we just need to find $k \equiv a^r + r \pmod p$ and it will work.

So..... let $r$ be any natural value you want.

Let $k = a^r+r + mp$ for any $m$ we like.  Let $n = k(p-1)+r$.

That's it.

$a^n + n \equiv a^{k(p-1)}a^r + n \equiv a^r + n = $

$a^r + k(p-1) + r\equiv a^r -k + r = a^r -(a^r +r + mp)+r =-mp\equiv 0 \pmod p$.